# Sitecore - Upload two file with same name but different extension inside a zip file

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I want to upload 2 files with same name but different extension, i want to put them inside a zip file and then use sitecore to extract all the files into the sitecore media library.
I'm using sitecore 7.2. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Upload Files (Advanced)` option and then select the `Unpack ZIP Archives` in the upload dialog.

[image: Upload Files (Advanced)]

[image: Unpack ZIP]

The file will be uploaded, the archived unpacked and resulting files individually listed as separate items:

[image: Upload Files with same name]

The issue you have with the above is that Sitecore is very "flexible" (*ahem*) with what it allows as an item extension, therefore it cannot resolve both of these items, since they both have the same Item name.

You can either set `Media.IncludeExtensionsInItemNames=true` in config or extend the `MediaRequestHandler` to make additional checks for the extension: [Handling Duplicate Media Paths in Sitecore.](http://sitecoreskills.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/handling-duplicate-media-paths-in.html)

There's more info about this behaviour in [this previous Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066680/sitecore-media-items-and-urls).

NOTE: The `Unpack ZIP archives` does not appear to be working in Sitecore 8, Update 4 (possibly all). I will raise it as a bug with support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normal asp.net file upload to upload the zip to a directory on the web server.

You can then use the Sitecore `ZipReader` to unpack zip files and create media items:

```cs
 using (ZipReader zipReader = new ZipReader(str))
 {
                foreach (ZipEntry entry in zipReader.Entries)
                {
                    if (entry.IsDirectory)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    MediaUploadResult mediaUploadResult = new MediaUploadResult();
                    list.Add(mediaUploadResult);
                    mediaUploadResult.Path = FileUtil.MakePath(this.Folder, entry.Name, '/');
                    mediaUploadResult.ValidMediaPath = MediaPathManager.ProposeValidMediaPath(mediaUploadResult.Path);
                    MediaCreatorOptions mediaCreatorOption = new MediaCreatorOptions()
                    {
                        Language = this.Language,
                        Versioned = this.Versioned,
                        KeepExisting = !this.Overwrite,
                        Destination = mediaUploadResult.ValidMediaPath,
                        FileBased = this.FileBased,
                        Database = this.Database
                    };
                    MediaCreatorOptions mediaCreatorOption1 = mediaCreatorOption;
                    mediaCreatorOption1.Build(GetMediaCreatorOptionsArgs.UploadContext);
                    Stream stream = entry.GetStream();
                    mediaUploadResult.Item = MediaManager.Creator.CreateFromStream(stream, mediaUploadResult.Path, mediaCreatorOption1);
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: yeah, but i really want a solution from the sitecore backend. But thanks

Comment: what part do you need help with exactly?

Comment: I already found an answer. It looks like this is more like config problem. And i already solved this

Comment: MediaUploadResult's properties are internal/readonly. The above code won't compile